# How to add a field to an ArrayList from a different class?

Tags: java

I'm quite new to programming, I'm building a program that adds different jobs done by the same person in an organisation to an ArrayList.

I'm trying to add more than two job titles from the main class to the ArrayList but I keep getting an error, could you please guide me in the right direction?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;                                                 
public class Employee
{
 private String name;
  private String department;


  private ArrayList<String>job = new ArrayList();

 public void setJob(ArrayList<String> job)
  {
  this.job =job;
 }  

 public ArrayList<String> getJob()
 {
   return job;
 }  
 }
```

Here is the Main class
    public class Main

```
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {

  Employee walter = new Employee();
   walter.setName("Walter White");
   walter.setJob("Chemistry Teacher");//The error occurs here it says 
   //method setJob in class Employee cannot be applied to given types;
```

walter.setJob("Chemistry Teacher");
^
required: java.util.ArrayList
found: java.lang.String
reason: actual argument java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.util.ArrayList by method invocation conversion

```
   walter.setDepartment("Science");
  }
  }
```

Comment: `"but I keep getting an error..."` ??? -- but you don't tell or show the error message to us. Why leave us in the dark, please show us your complete error message.

Comment: Wait... why does the `setJob(...)` method take an ArrayList? Why is the job field an ArrayList?

Comment: `walter.getJob().add("Chemistry Teacher");`

Comment: Oh i thought that's the correct type you needed to add a job?

Comment: That really doesn't make sense. How many jobs does one Employee have? If one, then you should not be using an ArrayList. If many, then perhaps you want to give the class an `addJob(String job)` method that adds that String to the ArrayList.

Comment: An Employee can have many Jobs in this case, okay I will try that.

Comment: Thank you Elliot Frisch! It worked!

Comment: If your requirement is that an employee have many jobs than there is nothing wrong with defining it as a list. The more elegant way would be to follow the suggestion of @HovercraftFullOfEels but since you are a starter you should know that it is not wrong per se

Comment: I don't agree with @ElliottFrisch's solution as it exposes the class's fields unnecessarily. Instead I continue to suggest what I mentioned above -- give your class an `addJob(String job)` method that in its body add's the String to the ArrayList.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I tried your solution as well, it worked, thank you!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I added my comment based on OP's existing code. Using `addJob(String)` transitions more from *comment* to *answer*. But OP really ought to elaborate on the desired relationship between Employee and Job (and department).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: The question seemed from the start to be a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) type question, a type of question that invites bad answers.

Comment: Original poster, don't accept that bad answer, please

Answer (score 2):

You defined `job` as an `ArrayList` of `String`, therefore you **can't** set it with a plain String you must pass a List to it. Here is **one way** to do it:

```
walter.setJob(Arrays.asList(new String("Chemistry Teacher")));
```

Or less verbal way as suggested by @Daedalus

```
walter.setJob(Arrays.asList("Chemistry Teacher"));
```

If your requirement is that an employee have many jobs than there is nothing wrong with defining it as a list. The more elegant way would be to follow the suggestion of @HovercraftFullOfEels in comments above but since you are a starter you should know that it is not wrong per se.

His suggestion is that you have a method to add a job to the existing list so:

```
public void addJob(String jobName){
    job.add(jobName);
}
```

Then you would use:

```
 walter.addJob("Chemistry Teacher");
```

Comment: new String("Chemistry Teacher") can be written as just "Chemistry Teacher", other than that this answer seems fine to me.