# Why should I create function Add?

Tags: java, c#

Most of expert programmer here have down voted my answer as bad answer

> [How to add a field to an ArrayList from a different class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43131374/how-to-add-a-field-to-an-arraylist-from-a-different-class/43131540#43131540)

So, I wonder why do I need to create another function `Add` to add items to my list. While most of programming language such as `Java` `C#` and `VB.NET` allow us a very simple way by using `Getter` as a List or ArrayList that we be able to add and use many function that this class has directly as sample as bellow

C#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.lst.Add("Hello");
    }
}
class Employee
{
    private List<string> _lst = new List<string>();

    public List<string> lst
    {
        get { return _lst; }
    }
    //public void add(String item) {
    //    _lst.Add(item);
    //}
}
```

Java

```
    public class MainApp {
        public static void main(String[] args){     
            Employee emp = new Employee();
            emp.getLst().add("My String");
        }
    }

    class Employee{
       private List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();

       public List<String> getLst() {
            return lst;
       }
       public void setLst(List<String> lst) {
           this.lst = lst;
       }
   }
```

Most of languages are allow us to do this ways. So, what is the reason I need to create function `Add` for on Employee?

Comment: This is an OOP technique called encapsulation and it isn't ***required*** just ***recommended*** in certain scenarios.

Comment: Correct answer != useful answer (which is what drives votes). If you want to discuss why your original answer got downvotes it is better to do that on Meta.

Comment: So I need to write some methods that I'm going to access my list for CRUD all the time is the best practice?

Comment: This is best practice. For readability.

Comment: The purpose of *encapsulation* is that your class (`Employee`) is in full control of its member values. If it returns the `List` itself, and lets callers modify that list, then you have broken the encapsulation, because the class is no longer in control. E.g. a nefarious caller could assign the list to a *raw* `List` variable, then add an `Integer` object. Or if `Employee` wants to ensure that values cannot be null or empty strings, the `add()` method could validate that, but not if a caller can modify list directly.

Comment: Would you rather type `emp.getLst().add();` evrytime you want to add somethind to the list or `emp.add("My String")`.  Most of the time you will need an `add` method for convenience and/or to hide implementation detail.

Comment: the problem in the original question was something a bit different, what you suggested side stepped the actual problem.

Comment: Imagine you had thousand of developers using your wonderful API, which correctly had a method `emp.add("My String")` which added the String to a List.  Now imagine that you wanted to change it so that an Employee now could only have one Job.  Having correctly defined your method, you could make the changes in the API and all the developers would not need to change their code at all - Big win

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Practical reason: `getList()` may return either internal list or copy of that list. There is no way for consumer of the class to know what is the behavior of the method without knowing implementation of `getList()` (or less likely find and read documentation on that particular method of particular class). So adding to or modifying result of `getList()` call  in any other way may never change the original object and proving correctness will require reading all the code including (frequently private) implementation of `getList()`.

Whether it is useful to expose separate methods to add to the list or not is personal choice based on particular code. Generally it is better to provide specific methods for all operations on the object as one can guarantee consistency of the state of the object.

For example if object is plain data transfer object having raw lists is fine there, but if it is `Student` exposing modifiable list of classes may easily lead to inconsistent state if for example total score class is stored independently.